# Inserting into mysql from javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

I am attempting to build a basic higher or lower game in javascript and insert the results into a table in mysql. After that I am attempting to display the top ten results. Currently I have a rough outline of the game that functions with but am stuck on how to pass the three java script variables to php to insert. I looked up a method of doing this in Ajax an attempted to implement but have not had success yet.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){
   $username = $_SESSION['username'];
   print $username;
}

?>

<body onload="random()">

<p>Welcome to the higher or lower game</p>
<p>Please enter a guess betweeen 1 and 100</p>

<form id="userGuess">
  <input id="ui" type="text" name="UserInput" value="">
</form> 
<br>
  <br><br>
  higher or lower
  <br><br>
<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="status"></p>
<p id="rand"></p>
<p id="nan"></p>


<button onclick="comparison()">Submit</button>
<button onclick="reset()">Reset</button>

<script>
var numGuess = 0;
var userIn;
var randNum = 0;
var status;
var method;
//var nan;

function comparison(){
//isnan and parseint

userIn = document.getElementById("ui").value;
//suserIn = parseint(userIn);
//if(isnan(parseint(userIn)){
//  nan = "true"
//}
//else{
//  nan = "false"
//}
if(userIn == randNum){
    //User wins
    status = "Correct"
    method = "submitScore";
    getData({method:"submitScore", score:numGuess, username:username});


window.location = 'http://icarus.cs.weber.edu/~ka14804/3750/A1/results.php'
    }
else if(userIn < randNum){
    //output higher
    status = "Higher"
    numGuess++;
}
else if(userIn > randNum){
    //output lower
    status = "Lower"
    numGuess++;
}
document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = status;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = userIn;
document.getElementById("rand").innerHTML = randNum;
document.getElementById("nan").innerHTML = nan;
document.getElementById("nan").innerHTML = numGuess
;
//compare random number to user input. Output higher, lower or match.

}

function reset(){
    random();
    numGuess = 0;

}

function random() {
    randNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
}



function getData(obj,callback){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'resulta.php',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: "json",
        data: obj
    }).done(function(data) {
        if(callback != null)
            callback(data);
    });
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

results.php

```
<?php

class Results {
    public $data;
    public $success = true;
    public $errorMessage;
}

$func = $_GET["method"];
$obj = new Results();



switch ($func) {

        case "getHighScores":
        $conn = new  mysqli('localhost','','','');
        if (!$conn->connect_errno) {
            $high = "SELECT * FROM HighScores ORDER BY Score LIMIT 10";
            $scores = $conn->query($high);
            $arr = array();
            while ($row = $scores->fetch_assoc()){
                $arr[] = $row;
            }
            $obj->data = $arr;
            echo json_encode($obj);
        }
        break;
    case "submitScore":
        $userName = $_GET["username"];
        $score = $_GET["score"];
        $conn = new  mysqli('localhost','','','');
        if (!$conn->connect_errno) {
            $query = "INSERT INTO HIGHSCORES VALUES('" . $userName . "', '" . $score . "')";
            $conn->query($query);
        }
        break;
    default:
        echo "Invalid method";
        break;
    }

?>
```

Comment: What happens with this code? Do you get any errors? You also will be open to SQL injections with this method. You should parameterize your queries.

Comment: I am not getting any errors when I get the correct number and submit. I am attempting to get it functioning then I will put that in place as well as some error handing.

Comment: Please describe what is wrong. From your last comment it sounds like it is working and you are going to add in functionality later?

Comment: It is not submitting the username and score into the database. I am displaying the random number on the page for testing purposes and when I type the correct number and hit submit nothing happens. There is something wrong with my ajax I believe but i'm not sure what.

Comment: `resulta.php` is a typo? Open the developer console and see what happens with the request.

Comment: @chris85 Yes that was a typo and I also found from looking at the console and googling that I needed to include <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>. Not I am at least getting to my results page however I am getting an error undefined index at $func = $_GET["method"]; on the results page.

Comment: Look at your `$_GET` and see what you have `print_r($_GET);`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155721/discussion-between-k455306-and-chris85).